# UISlider Handle Changes Width on Different Size iPads

Tags: swift, ipad, interface-builder, constraints, uislider

I have a vertical slider which uses the following code to generate a handle image within its custom class:

```
func generateHandleImage(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage {


    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (superview?.bounds.size.height)! * 0.07,
                      height: (superview?.bounds.size.width)!)


    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size).image { (imageContext) in
        imageContext.cgContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        imageContext.cgContext.fill(rect.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0))
    }
}
```

I have set the autolayout constraints in IB for the slider for it to be centered in the x & y axes of it's superview and equal widths and heights with the heights and widths of it's superview (since it is a vertical slider).

this is the code which makes my slider vertical and calls the function to generate the handle image:

```
// Make Sliders Vertical
    let sliderTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2) + CGFloat(M_PI))
    pitchBendSlider.transform = sliderTransform

    pitchBendSlider.setThumbImage(pitchBendSlider.generateHandleImage(with: .white), for: .normal)
```

I want the handle image to be equal to the width of it's superview.  It does this correctly on an iPad Air 2 in iOS simulator, but on an iPad Pro 12.9" it is about 80-90% of the superview's width, and on an iPad Air it is slightly bigger than the superview's width.

How can I make the width of the custom slider's image handle equal to it's superview's width on all iPad sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Through trial & error I discovered this was a "timing issue".  The handle image rect was being drawn too soon in `viewDidLoad`.

My "hack" solution was to place the function that draws the slider handle into the button action function which calls the views to appear (which has the vertical slider inside it).

Adding a timing delay would probably solve the problem just the same.  Both are hack solutions, and I still lack the understanding of why the proper screen size is not recognized prior to `viewDidLoad` being called in the VC which contains the vertical slider...

However, this solved the problem.